Get union type for Set members
Given a type of a Set with union of members:
type MySet = Set<"foo" | "bar">;

How would one extract a union type for its members, like this:
type MySetMembers = "foo" | "bar";


Those aren’t members of a set. They are items

The alternative to MySet extends Set<infer M> ? M : never would be something like ReturnType<MySet['entries']> but it's more complicated than that

The duped answer did not work, but I figured it out myself now: type SetValues<T extends Set<unknown>> = T extends Set<infer I> ? I : never; followed by SetValues<MySet>.
